# Check if search query is entered or not

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, searchqueryset

I made a search bar for my website with bootstrap everything is fine now the problem is that it can also be used when nothing is entered.

So how can i check for that with php and also add a min letter to search.

Just give me a rough idea that what I can  do!

Comment: Show us some code.. How does it look, what have you done so far? What are you expecting, what's failing?

Comment: Well server side you can do `!empty`, to confirm the input isn't empty; you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php to check for a minimum length..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the simplest solution is add `required` to it for eg.

```
<input type = "text" name = "yoursearchbox" required>
```

Comment: i know there a lot of solutions to get this done using client-side javascript or through other scripting languages like php but that would require a deep understanding of various functions to achieve that so i put the simplest..

Comment: wow worked and that was so simple :) But can i put custom error message if no query entered.

Comment: Yes you can put custom error messages but you need to learn JavaScript or php or any other language of your choice to achieve that.. go for some online tutorials..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `HTML5` you can use `required`:

```
<input type="text" name="search" required>
```

In `PHP`, you can validate in a number of ways, like so:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST["search"])        //The value is not set
        ||empty(@$_POST["search"])     //The value is empty
        ||strlen(@$_POST["search"])<1) //The string is shorter than 1 character
    {
        //Search is empty
    }
```